# Is it legal to call virtual functions without a base pointer

Tags: c++, polymorphism

This code works but I can't tell if it's legal.
I'm instantiating the most derived class `Three` and then calling its function `run()` which happens to be implemented in the base class `One`.  That function then calls its own function `fn1()`, and then the two virtual functions `fn2()` and `fn3()`.
I seem to be calling virtual functions without a polymorphic pointer.  Am I somehow using the `this` pointer?  Am I doing anything wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
class One
{
    public:
    void fn1()
    {
        std::cout << "fn1 runs" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void fn2() = 0;
    virtual void fn3() = 0;
    void run()
    {
        fn1();
        fn2();
        fn3();
    }
};

class Two : public One
{
public:
    virtual void fn2() final
    {
        std::cout << "fn2 runs" << std::endl;
    }


};

class Three : public Two
{
    public:
    virtual void fn3() final
    {
        std::cout << "fn3 runs" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Three x;
    x.run();
}
```

Result, as expected:

```
fn1 runs
fn2 runs
fn3 runs
```

Comment: what is your problem ? *x* is a *Tree* so virtual methods *fn1 fn2* and *fn3* are defined for *x* and can be called. Do you understand what inheritance and *virtual* methods are ?

Comment: As stated in the question I couldn't work out if it is legal because there is no explicit base pointer.

Comment: all is applied on the instance memorized by *x*, you really need to read books about C++

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because if I had read all the books on C++ I wouldn't have needed to ask the Stack Overflow community.  I thought that was a reasonable thing to do but now realise that Stack Overflow is a *last resort* and it would have been possible for me to get the answer from somewhere else albeit in completely different time frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `fn1` is a non-static member function, `fn1()` implicitly means `this->fn1()`. Same goes for `fn2()` and `fn3()`.

Comment: So it is legal and reasonable to do that you mean?

Comment: @Ant obviousy, all of that is the base of C++

Comment: @Ant Legal, yes. Stylistically, most C++ programmers agree that it's acceptable to omit the `this->`.